# Feature upgrade in SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, feature-upgrade

Can we do feature upgrade in SharePoint Online, like we do in SharePoint on-premise.

Please suggest some articles.

Comment: Do you want to upgrade sandbox solution feature in SharePoint Online?

Comment: Yes, I want to upgrade Sandbox Solution feature.

Comment: Kindly check my answer below. :)

Comment: Did you get it? Kindly let me know if needs more help.

Comment: I am working on that,will keep you posted.

Comment: Thanks buddy..Please let me know if you have any problem in that..

Comment: Waiting for your reply so i can assist someone with same solution..

Comment: Have you achieved the resolution?

Comment: No additional steps required for upgrading the solution in SharePoint online.Even I did not have to write UpgradeActions in Elements.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same thing. But as we do not have any means to upgrade the feature in O365 still I wrote the `UpgradeActions` tags in the feature.xml anyway. But as expected it threw an exception.

Then it struck me that whenever you go to update the wsp in SharePoint Online, it asks you to deactivate and upload then activate again.

Deactivating the wsp causes removal of all your fields(created by wsp) and content types and when you activate it, it adds/deploys them again. So, I removed the `UpgradeActions` and added new fields to my content type as I generally would for the first deployment and voila! It not only updated my content type but also updated the existing list.

I don't know if that will help you.

Comment: Did it working for you?

Comment: Yes It's worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I am here considering that you are asking about the upgrading sandbox solution's features.

> To update the solution in SharePoint Online, first we will need an
>   updated WSP. It should have the relevant sections specified in the
>   UpgradeActions Feature XML element.

Kindly check below article which describes the same.

[Install and Update Sandbox Solutions with CSOM](http://www.vrdmn.com/2015/11/install-and-update-sandbox-solutions.html)

[Upgrading Sandbox Solutions in SharePoint](https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2014/08/21/upgrading-sandbox-solutions-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: Hello Hardik, I had a different experience with upgrading feature. As I am new to SharePoint, please check my answer below and let me know if this is in fact the "feature" provided by SharePoint Online.

Comment: Please check in this link for step by step instructions to upgrade the solution..https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2014/08/21/upgrading-sandbox-solutions-in-sharepoint/

Comment: Did you guys get it working for you?